# Perl : background process not running because of print statement

Tags: linux, perl, unix, background-process

I want to run a perl file in background ( linux machine) for which i use 
 **&** but due to print statement in it i can't run in background. 
example: test.pl

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 print "Hello world";
 while (1)
 {
 }
```

when i run this in background as perl test.pl **&** it hangs , but when i comment the print statement it runs in background properly .
My actual code is huge this is just an example for which i need solution , 
     this is just a prototype, actually i am doing concurrent server in perl, so i need to run that in background and print the debug info, i have tried many things but unable to handle this situation of running in background, even after commenting the prints now it still doesn't run in bkgrnd

Comment: add nohup ad the beginning of your command: nohup perl test.pl &

Comment: run it as `perl test.pl >/dev/null 2>&1 &` (or direct output suitably if you want to see it).  If it may read from stdin you may want to add `</dev/null` which will cause it to get EOF when it reads.

Comment: @Jens added that as well still not running in background

Comment: @tfb ; this is a sample , i need to print stuff for debugging purpose as my org script is very big, do u suggest to take the print statements in a log.txt or something ?

Comment: @hanish Yes, but I was wrong: it almost certainly is running as Dave Sherohnman's answer says.  You only need to redirect output if you want it to outlive its parent shell.

Answer (score 1):

Your program *is* running in the background.  This can be simply verified using the `ps` command.  e.g., `ps ax | grep name_of_your_script`

The reason you aren't seeing the printed output is because of output buffering.  If you add a newline to your print (`print "Hello world\n";` - note the `\n`), then the output buffer will be flushed immediately, causing the text to appear on your screen.

Comment: the output gets printed , but the process hangs as in the bash doesn't ask me for another command, i have to give a Ctrl-Z or Ctrl-C to come back to execute the next command, i tried with \n as well still it doesn't work.

Comment: You may need to provide a more complete example, in that case. For the posted example, the only code after the `print` is `while (1) { }`, so "hanging" forever, until you kill the process, is the expected (and correct) behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl test.pl >/dev/null`, the output will be transferred to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

When things other than your shell and its foreground job are writing to the terminal, you can't assume that everything will be printed in a convenient order.

Maybe you didn't notice the prompt because it's above the background process's output. Or maybe the shell prompt has been overwritten by the output of the background process because of unfortunate timing of cursor movements.

Those things can happen since the shell and background process are both writing to the terminal at the same time with no coordination between them.

Your shell might be waiting for you to type a command, even though the prompt and cursor aren't where you expect them to be. Go ahead and type a command and see if it works. Or just hit Enter to get a new prompt. In zsh the `redisplay` action (Ctrl-R in vi mode) is a good thing to use in this situation. bash doesn't have an equivalent as far as I know.